# Check for multiple containers in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm really fresh to jQuery and trying to alter a function to apply changes to a number of div's. Im using Primož Cigar's ["Neat trick for CSS Object-fit fallback on EDGE"](https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3) to detect if Object fit is supported in the browser and if not, copy the src of the image to the background image source of the container. This works very well, but my issue is i have four different image container divs i need to target to apply the same function.

```
   if ( ! Modernizr.objectfit ) {
  $('.post__image-container').each(function () {
    var $container = $(this),
        imgUrl = $container.find('img').prop('src');
    if (imgUrl) {
      $container
        .css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')')
        .addClass('compat-object-fit');
    }  
  });
}
```

Lets say i want to apply the same function to .header__image-container and .banner__image-container how do i properly restructure the code above?

Comment: Can't you just add a global class of `container` as well as the unique ones and use the `.each()` on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to add a global class such as `container` i.e

HTML

```
<div class="container container1"></div>
<div class="container container2"></div>
<div class="container container3"></div>
```

Then restructure your code so it search through each `.container` rather than a single class.

```
if ( ! Modernizr.objectfit ) {
  $('.container').each(function () {
    var $container = $(this),
        imgUrl = $container.find('img').prop('src');
    if (imgUrl) {
      $container
        .css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')')
        .addClass('compat-object-fit');
    }  
  });
}
```